# node.js-10:TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Hi I'm trying to upload image in new folder but it says:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined:

My code:

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
        var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
            var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
            var newpath = 'D:/nodejs/images/' + files.filetoupload.name;
            fs.rename(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
                res.end();
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
        res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">');
        res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
        res.write('<input type="submit">');
        res.write('</form>');
        return res.end();
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

Comment: it seems that `files` or `files.filetoupload` are `undefined`. Can you please add `console.dir(files);` and post the output?

Comment: your code is working on my device (to be fair it crashes when tries to access to `D:/` , which is fine because i am on linux.

Comment: @Thecave3  ReferenceError: files is not defined
    at Server.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\app.js:169:14)
    at Server.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at parserOnIncoming (_http_server.js:677:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)

Comment: @Thecave3 m using windows

Comment: have you installed the dependencies?